# isometric embedding of a sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Hi,

Is there a way to find a function $F : \mathbb S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ of class $\mathcal C^1$, minimizing 
$$\int_{\mathbb S^2\times\mathbb S^2} (d(F(x),F(y)) - \delta(x,y))^2 ~dx ~dy$$
, where $d$ stands for the euclidean distance in $\mathbb R^3$ and $\delta$ the geodesic distance on the sphere $\mathbb S^2$?

I tried to perform a Multi-Dimensional Scaling to get this least square solution for a finite set of point, but it seems that the solution was just the identity... is that right?

Thanks!

Comment: I have no clue what the OP is asking for. Voting to close unless clarified.

Comment: I did my best to rewrite the question and clarify. Thanks for the feedbacks.

Comment: Let me understand if I understood correctly. You have $n$ points $p_1, \cdots , p_n$ on the standard unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. You're asking about the existence of points $q_1, \cdots , q_n$ on $\mathbb{S}^2$ such that $d(q_i,q_j)=\delta (p_i,p_j)$, where $d$ is the Euclidean distance and $\delta$ is the geodesic distance w.r.t. the spherical metric?

Comment: yes - up to the fact that an approximation is fine if an exact solution cannot be found ; and that the $q_i$ could be anywhere in $R^3$, not necessarily on $S^2$

Comment: (continued)  ...and you want the assignement $p_i \mapsto q_i$ to be realized by the same function $F=(f,g,h):\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{S}^2$. Which regularity are you assuming about $F$ ? Does it have to extend to a function (with the same regularity) $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I just read the new comment: so, $F:\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$. 

Comment: Which regularity are you assuming $F$ to have? Continuous, differentiable...? Also, what do you mean by "approximation"?

Comment: yes. The higher regularity the better, but I'm fine if F is just $C^1$...

Comment: by approximation, I mean $d(q_i,q_j) \approx \delta(p_i,p_j)$, where $\approx$ could stand for a least square solution or anything reasonnably similar.

Comment: (the MDS should already give the least-square solution, but what I obtain is just the identity... which makes me think there may be nothing better)

Comment: Could you please edit your question so that it is more readable, adding the relevant "quantifiers" in the right order, if possible? Like: given points... for every $\epsilon >0$... we're looking for an 
$F$ of class $\mathcal{C}^1$ such that... 

Comment: done. Thanks for helping me clarify the question!

Comment: It seems, given $p_i\in\mathbb{S}^2$, you are looking for an $F:\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ of class $\mathcal{C}^1$ that minimizes the quantity $\Sigma_{i,j} (d(F(p_i),F(p_j))-\delta (p_i,p_j))^2$. Is that correct?

Comment: yes indeed... I'll further clarify ;)

Comment: A couple of remarks: 1) the regularity is not a relevant point here, because the minimization problem only concerns functions defined on the finite set $\\{p_i \\}$, and a minimizer of this discrete problem can be extended smoothly and canonically to the sphere. 2) The identity is certainly not a minimizer, because $(1+\epsilon)Id$ is better, for any $\epsilon > 0$ small enough.

Comment: 1) Indeed - Ideally, I'd like a function defined on the whole $S^2$ and not to just find a solution for a particular set of points. Re-formulating multiple times this question made me converge to this question on a finite set of points, but I'd rather have the solution of the more general problem.
2) ok

Comment: I rephrased again to get an answer to the continuous case. Sorry for the multiple edits!

Comment: Do you know the answer for $S^1\to\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: no, I don't... what is it ?

Comment: Maybe you should work out the answer for the circle before you try to do it for the 2-sphere. I do not know but I suspect that was the point of Anton's question.

Comment: ok. I thought this was a known result in geometry, since it allows to approximate geodesic distances on the sphere with euclidean distances, which should be a rather common problem.

Answer (score 3):

Although I cannot answer your question precisely, I thought I would suggest a possible direction
to pursue: embeddings of finite metric spaces with low distortion.
With those keywords you will hit a rich literature.
Perhaps the place to start is this Handbook article by Piotr Indyk and Jiri Matousek:

> "Low distortion embeddings of finite metric spaces,"
>   *Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry*,
>   177-196, CRC, 2004. ([Google books link](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=QS6vnl8WlnQC&oi=fnd&pg=PA177&dq=Low-Distortion+Embeddings+of+Finite+Metric+Spaces&ots=4AEFXZyElc&sig=ZD0jADcN2O-LK3Qq4dC4VfwKeUc#v=onepage&q=Low-Distortion%2520Embeddings%2520of%2520Finite%2520Metric%2520Spaces&f=false))

For example, Bourgain's embedding theorem say that any $n$-point metric space can 
be embedded in $\ell_2$ with $O( \log n )$ distortion 
(where *distortion* is defined
by a factor times the source distance $\delta(x,y)$ bounding the target distance—not quite your
least squares, but a reasonable measure).
Unfortunately this embedding might be into a rather high
dimension, which is not what you want.
Matousek proved that there are $n$-point metric spaces that
require distortion $\Omega(n^{1/2})$ for embedding into $\ell^3_2$ (i.e., $\mathbb{R^3}$),
which does not bode well for your problem.

Unfortunately, negative results abound.  Here is one, not directly relevant (because both spaces have $n$ points), but its more recent references may help:

> "Hardness of Embedding Metric Spaces of Equal Size,"
>   Subhash Khot and
>   Rishi Saket,
>   *[Proceedings of the 10th International Workshop on Approximation](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1459754)*, 2007.

To skirt these negative results, you might have to somehow exploit the fact that your
source distances are geodesics on a sphere.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "n-point metric" : does it mean that we consider a discrete space consisting of only n points ? In this case, the result can be directly obtained constructively using methods such as MDS, IsoMap, LLE, eigenmaps ..., isn't it ? Or is it different ?

Comment: Yes, $n$ points with distances forming a metric space, as satisfied by $n$ points on a sphere.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that the sphere is with the center at $(0,0,0)$ and has the radius $1$. Let's take the points $p_1=(0,0,1)$, $p_2=(0,0,-1)$, $p_3=(1,0,0)$, $p_4=(0,1,0)$. The distances are $\delta(p_1,p_3)=\delta(p_1,p_4)=\delta(p_3,p_4)=\delta(p_2,p_3)=\delta(p_2,p_4)=\pi/2$, and $=\delta(p_1,p_2)=\pi$. Now let's try to find in $\mathbb R^3$ four points $q_i$ at the same distances. $q_1,q_3,q_4$ and $q_2,q_3,q_4$ are equilateral triangles, with the length of the edges equal to $\pi_2$. The distance $d(q_1,q_2)\leq \pi\sqrt 3/2$. But we need to have $d(q_1,q_2)=\pi$, and this cannot happen.

---

**Edit:**
It seems that the question has changed. I'll let this counterexample anyway.

Comment: ok, thanks, this already tells me that an exact solution cannot be found. Do you know about a least-square solution ? Thanks!